# Sitemesh2 is discontinued, Sitemesh3 is ALPHA - what now?

Tags: java, spring, sitemesh

I kind of accidentally stumbled upon opensymphony's website stating that they went out of business - but their projects (at least some) will be continued over the course of time by others.

However, I'm relying on sitemesh 2.4.2 in on of my applications. This application should be sort of future safe in regards to the used frameworks and technologies.
So I had a look at Sitemesh3, which unfortunately is still in alpha stage (http://www.sitemesh.org/).

I really *LOVED* how little effort it took to use sitemesh decorators and how it integrated into spring mvc. 
I had a look at Apache Tiles and albeit nice looking it sort of turned me off when I saw that I had to write an xml entry for every view I needed - quite the hassle I think.

Or am I missing something with tiles? I want to keep on using JSPs but I'm looking for a worry-free templating system like sitemesh.

What can you guys suggest?
Just keep on using sitemesh2?
Make the switch to sitemesh3 alpha?

Comment: Do not choose the path of sitemesh or forever it will dominate your density.

Comment: the dark side has cookies though - i want to stay there :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep using Sitemesh 2. The project is still alive on Github:

https://github.com/sitemesh/sitemesh2